# what's the code meaning?

Tags: php

```
$file = fopen("test.txt","r");
while($line = fgets($file)) {
  $line = trim($line);
  list($model,$price) = preg_split('/\s+/',$line);
  if(empty($price)) {
    $price = 0;
  }
  $sql = "UPDATE products
          SET products_price=$price
          WHERE products_model='$model'";    
  // run the sql query.
}
fclose($file);
```

the txt file like this:

```
model  price
LB2117  19.49
LB2381  25.99
```

1, what's the meaning of   `list($model,$price) = preg_split('/\s+/',$line);`
i know `preg_split` like `explode`, but i don't know what't the parameter meaning of the above line
2, how to skip the first record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's taking the results of the `preg_split` and assigning them to the vars `$model` and `$price`. You're looking at a parsing algorithm. Sorry if this is not enough. I have a hard time understanding the question as it is written.

Also, if I read this correctly, there is no need to skip line 1 unless you have an item with the model defined as "model" in the database.

But if you wanted to for some reason, you could add a counter...

```
$i = 0;
while($line = fgets($file)) {
  if($i > 0)
  {
    $line = trim($line);
    list($model,$price) = preg_split('/\s+/',$line);
    if(empty($price)) {
      $price = 0;
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE products
          SET products_price=$price
          WHERE products_model='$model'";    
    // run the sql query.
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: but when i run the code it shows an error,Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\www\update.php on line 11. the line 11 is list($model,$price)=preg_split('/\s+/',$line);

Answer (score 1):

That is a language construct that allows you to assign to multiple variables at once. You can think of it as array unpacking (`preg_split` returns an array). So, when you do:

```
<?php
list($a, $b) = explode(".","a.b");
echo $a . "\n";
echo $b . "\n";
```

You will get:

```
a
b
```

Having less elements in list than the array is ok, excess elements in array are ignored, but having insufficent elements in array will give you an undefined index error. For example:

```
list($a) = explode(".","a.b"); // ok
list($a,$b,$c) = explode(".","a.b") // error
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you meant that by skip the first record but...

```
$file = fopen("test.txt","r"); // open file for reading
$first = true;
while($line = fgets($file)) {  // get the content file
  if ($first === true) { $first = false;}//skip the first record 
  else{
  $line = trim($line);         // remove the whitespace before and after the test 
                               // not in the middle
  list($model,$price) = preg_split('/\s+/',$line); // create two variable model and price, the values are from the preg_split \s means whitespace, tab and linebreak
  if(empty($price)) {          // if $price is empty price =0
    $price = 0;
  }
  $sql = "UPDATE products      // sql update
          SET products_price=$price
          WHERE products_model='$model'";    
  // run the sql query.
  }
}
fclose($file);                 //close the file
```

Comment: but when i run the code it shows an error,Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\www\update.php on line 11. the line 11 is list($model,$price)=preg_split('/\s+/',$line);